# Two statements about sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

My teacher told me two statements about sequences . I'm looking for the proofs .

> **1** . Adding (or subtracting) finite number of terms doesn't affect to the status of the convergence.
>
> **2** . If $a_n$ converges to $l$ , every infinite subsequences of $a_n$ also converges to $l.$

My try : For instance consider $\{1 , 2 , 3 , 2.9 , 2.99 , 2.999 \dots \}$ . If we remove $\{ 1, 2,3\}$ it converges to $3$ still . In the  other words we can remove the part which is not converges and the rest terms converge to a number .

For the second statement if we create different subsequences its convergence point doesn't change only distances to the convergence point will change . I have these ideas but I'm unable to use them for proving .

Comment: Please add what your thoughts are about the question. As it stands the question doesn't fit the rules described in the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: What are your thoughts on the statements? Try to mention them while asking a question.

Comment: Okay , Thanks .

Comment: @PhilJones I've edited it .

Comment: @SahibaArora Can you help me now ?

Comment: Definitions are your (indispensable) friends.  In this Question it is unclear if you are stuck because the definition of convergent sequence is unfamiliar or unknown, or because you are having a more specific difficulty applying the definition.  Lumping two such unrelated problems together suggests the former but you owe it to Readers to say how far you got.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using epsilons:

**1.** Let $s_n$ be a sequence and let $s_n \to s$. Now take any finite set of numbers $\{a_i\}$ of an arbitrary size $k$ and add them to the sequence, at any chosen index positions $\{p_i\}$, so that the number $a_i$ is at the index $p_i$.

The resulting sequence $\tilde s_n$ can we given explicitely as:

$$\tilde s_n = \begin{cases} a_i \qquad &n = p_i, \quad i \in \{1,2, ..., k\} \\ 
                             s_{n-d} \qquad &\text{otherwise}  \end{cases}$$

where $d(n) = |\{p_i : p_i < n \}|$, meaning, the number of indeces under consideration less than $n$, which is finite set. Note that this means that for $n>\max_i{p_i}$, it's true that $d(n) = k$, whence we have that $\tilde s_n = s_{n-k}$.

Now given $\epsilon$, there exists some $N_0$ such that $d(s_n,s) < \epsilon$ for $n> N_0$.

So put $\tilde N_0 = \max{(N_0 + k, \max p_i)}$.

Then we have that if $n > \tilde N_0$, then $$n> \max{(p_i)} $$ and

$$n > N_0 + k \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad n -k > N_0 $$

so that

$$ d(\tilde s_n,s) = d(s_{n -k},s) <\epsilon $$

You can easily modify this for removing elements for $s_n$, where $\tilde s_n$ becomes $s_{n+d}$ instead.

---

**2.**

Let $s_n$ converge to $s$ and let $s_{n_k}$ be an infinite subsequence.

Let $\epsilon$ be given. There exists some $N_0$ such that $n>N_0$ implies $d(s_n,s) < \epsilon $. So put $k_0 = \min{\{k : n_k > N_0}\} $, this value always exists, since $N_0$ is fixed and $n_k$'s are increasing integers. This means that: if $k> k_0$, then $ n_k > N_0$ so that

$$ d(s_{n_k},s) < \epsilon $$

---

Hope it helps!